# why my pdo query is inserting only the last row

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

hi i have a problem with inserting `data` my `pdo` `query` insert only a single `row`.

why last row is inserted 2 times, i,e `friday pm`

here is what i have done

**please see my constructed `query` here  http://phpio.net/s/54jc**

```
<?php   

function returnValuesNoOfTimes($count,$fields = array()){

    $str = str_repeat("(:{$fields['user_id']},:{$fields['day']},:{$fields['am_pm']}),",$count); 

   return rtrim($str,", ");        
}


function queryBuilderLocallyDone($data = array(),$fields = array(),$user_id,$object_count){


 /*Inserting user values*/  

$valuesTimes = returnValuesNoOfTimes($object_count,$fields);


  $db = getDB();   


  $sql1="INSERT INTO availability({$fields['user_id']},{$fields['day']},{$fields['am_pm']}) VALUES {$valuesTimes}";  



  $stmt1 = $db->prepare($sql1);               



    foreach($data as $avb){         

      $stmt1->bindParam("user_id", $user_id,PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $stmt1->bindParam("day",$avb['day'],PDO::PARAM_STR);  
      $stmt1->bindParam("am_pm",$avb['time'],PDO::PARAM_STR);                                           
    }   



   $stmt1->execute();        



     // $stmt1->execute();                 


}
```

my starting point to call above `functions`

```
   $data = [
      0 => ['day'=> 'monday','time'=>'am'],
      1 => ['day'=> 'friday','time'=>'pm']
    ];

    $user_id = 2;


    $total = count($data);

     $fields = ['id'=>'','user_id'=>'user_id','day'=>'day','am_pm'=>'am_pm'];   
     queryBuilderLocallyDone($data,$fields,$user_id,$total);
```

**Question: why last row is inserted 2 times ?**

please help me thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Prepare outside of the loop, bind and execute in the loop.

Comment: Where are your placeholders defined for the values?

Comment: i have written so much `code` to `execute query at once` but with below answer each time i have to execute.  please see its demo here http://phpio.net/s/5470

Comment: @EaB  what you did is not very good. Please check my edited answer for a better approach. It not only removes function burden (in terms of number of parameter passed), but also remove one unnecessary function code.

Answer (score 3):

please insert    $stmt1->execute();        in the foreach

```
foreach($data as $avb){         

  $stmt1->bindParam("user_id", $user_id,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt1->bindParam("day",$avb['day'],PDO::PARAM_STR);  
  $stmt1->bindParam("am_pm",$avb['time'],PDO::PARAM_STR);                                           
  $stmt1->execute();        
}
```